# How to change the height of the collection view in swift

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uicollectionview, uitextfield

I have a collection view and a text field on a ui view.
Initially, I have a text field at the top of the ui view and then I set the collection view top Anchor constraint to the bottom of the text field.

I want to implement a behavior where if I scroll down the collection view, the text field should disappear and the collection view's top should be at the top of the same ui view (this would hide the text field). When I scroll up, I want the constraints to be like the initial ones (container view's top Anchor should be set to the bottom of the text field). Any hint at how I might implement this behavior? I was hoping to implement this by updating the constraints when scrolling up and scrolling down happens. How can I implement this?

Comment: UICollectionView subclasses UIScrollView, so you can set your code as the `UIScrollViewDelegate` and handle the scroll events

Answer (score 0):

`UICollectionView` subclasses `UIScrollView`, so you can implement a `UIScrollViewDelegate` to get the scroll events.

Here is some code I use in one of my apps

- The bottom of the text field is constrained to the top of the collection view
- The top of the text field is constrained to the view's top layout guide - This is the constraint that is modified by the scroll view delegate code
- As the collection view scrolls up the text field will move up and fade out

```
extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        let textHeight = self.textField.frame.size.height + 2
        let offset = min(scrollView.contentOffset.y, textHeight)

        if offset >= 0 || self.textFieldConstraint.constant != 0 {
            self.textFieldConstraint.constant = -offset
            let percent = max(1 - offset/textHeight,0)
            self.textField.alpha = percent
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially you "push" the text field off the top of the screen, no more than its height+2

Comment: What is textFieldConstraint and searchHeight?

Comment: Sorry, in my original code I was hiding a search bar and I missed one edit to text field; I have fixed that.  The constraint is the top constraint of the text field - I have clarified that

Comment: This works perfectly, do you know why there is a space between textField and the navigation bar?

Comment: I'm not sure; I don't have a navigation bar in my view, so you may need to adjust the constraints to get it to work how you want, but the general technique should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution can work full for you try this, just add a UIScrollView view as parent and put your text field and collection view in scroll view, as set the constraint as you set.